# Ajax request url and display response in a div is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax request to a website and display only part of it. My code doesn't work and I can't see the reason. Also, how can I parse the object and display only parts of it (just one property)? Thanks a lot!

JS:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button',function(){
    $.ajax('http://ShakeItSpeare.com/api/sentence', {
     success: function(response){
      console.log(response)
   //console.log of response works 
        $('.screen').html(response).fadeIn();
      }
    })
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="buttonClick">
<button>click Me</button>
<ul class="screen"></ul>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="shakes.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the JSON property name you're trying to insert into the HTML should only insert that value.  For example, in your code below, I added the "sentence" property in "response.sentence".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button',function(){
    $.ajax('http://ShakeItSpeare.com/api/sentence', {
     success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        //changed original code from ".html(response)" to ".html(response.sentence)"
        $('.screen').html(response.sentence).fadeIn();
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Working code pen: [Working Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEGAQA)

Comment: Thanks but nothing is being displayed in the div. Can you see why?

Comment: Thanks too much!! It works now! Can you please explain why .html wasn't working and .text does? What is the difference? Thanks!!

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why it wasn't working.  Tried both in the codepen and they both work equally as well.

Comment: Mentioning that you changed `.html()` to `.text()` gives new users the impression `.html()` was wrong which is not accurate. They are different but either will work for this use. You could stand to lose that bit for clarity's sake :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Good suggestion. This has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this structure:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://ShakeItSpeare.com/api/sentence",
                    success: function(response) {

                        console.log(response);
                        console.log(response.sentence);
                        console.log(response.markov);
                        //console.log of response works

                        $('.screen').html(JSON.stringify(response)).fadeIn();
                        //$('.screen').html(response.sentence).fadeIn();

                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                        console.log(err.Message);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

---

Alternate method based on your comment:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#buttonClick').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://ShakeItSpeare.com/api/sentence",
                dataType:'text',  // specify dataType as text and you wont need to convert the JSON 
                success: function(response) {
                    //console.log of response works
                    $('.screen').html(response).fadeIn();

                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you know how I can display the whole object? So far I can only display it when I say response.sentence etc but not just response? Do I need to parse it and if so how?.JSON.parse(response) doesn't work

Comment: @javascript2016 Yep, just use `JSON.stringify(response)` which will convert the object to a string. See update above. JSON.parse would turn a string into an object, the opposite of what you want for your needs.

Comment: @javascript2016 Alternatively, you can specify `dataType:'text',` in the ajax options object and you wont have to convert the object at all, see new update above.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you should get the String from the Object.
It would be

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button',function(){
    $.ajax('http://ShakeItSpeare.com/api/sentence', {
     success: function(response){
      console.log(response)
   //console.log of response works 
        $('.screen').html(response["sentence"]); // Changed this one from "response" to "response["sentence"]
      }
    })
  });
});


Object {sentence: "Nor goodly ilion stand.", markov: 2}
```

Or stringify it.

Comment: I am getting the object when i console log it, but my main question was: why can't I display that in the div? I can't see why the code is wrong? Nothing is being displayed

Comment: Response is an object with "sentence" and "markov". If you want to get the sentence you have to give "response.sentence" or "response["sentence"]" to your DOM not just the object.

Comment: I do that now! $('.screen').html(response.sentence).fadeIn(); but still nothing being displayed

Comment: `$('.screen').html(response.sentence).fadeIn();` is working fine for me. There is nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the url key in the request

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button',function(){

    $.ajax({url:'http://ShakeItSpeare.com/api/sentence', //Add url: and move the {

     success: function(response){
      console.log(response)
        $('.screen').html(response).fadeIn();
      }
    })
  });
});
```

If the response that is coming back has a content-type of application/json then you won't need to do JSON.parse() If it is in json format but is a string then you can JSON.parse() it then use the data as an object.

If you do console.log(response) It should display the whole object back.

Comment: Looking at that URL, the response is Content-Type:application/json

Comment: <!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="buttonClick">
<button>click Me</button>
<ul class="screen"></ul>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 
 
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#buttonClick').on('click', 'button',function(){
        $.ajax({url:'http://ShakeItSpeare.com/api/sentence',
         success: function(response){
          console.log(response)
            $('.screen').html(response).fadeIn();
          }
        })
      });
    });
</script>
    </body>
    </html>

Answer (score -1):

put a semi-colon after console.log(response)

Comment: Advisable but not at all required